# Install a Drupal module from git on a production site

Tags: 8, users, composer

I would like to install the "Private-Message-Messenger" module on my Drupal 8 site, but the module is not available on drupal.org

It is only available on git.

If I install this module on my site in production, how will happen the update when the module will be available on drupal.org?

Should I uninstall the git module completely and install the drupal.org module?

Should I just do an update of the module?

Is it likely to break the site?

I specify that I use "Composer". I take this module as an example but this question is valid for all modules of the git.

https://github.com/jez500/Private-Message-Messenger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to install something from git with composer is not drupal specific: https://lornajane.net/posts/2014/use-a-github-branch-as-a-composer-dependency.

You just specifiy it as a repository as explained there.

Other than that, you already answered all our questions, once it will be on drupal.org, you can just remove that extra repository.

And yes, of course it can break your site. Any module theoretically can, and development versions even more so. There is no guarantee that updates will come with an upgrade path for existing installations. You will need to figure out that out by talking to the author about his plans.